# How to iterate a C++ map of maps

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, multimap, multi-mapping

I have a map of map

```
std::map< int, std::map<string, double> > myMap;
std::map< int, std::map<string, double> >::iterator itr;
```

Iterating it with:

```
   itr = myMap.find(nodeI);
   if (itr == myMap.end())
   {
        exit(1) ;
   }
```

results in the error:

> ```
>       error: no match for âoperator=â in 
>       âitr = ((const PushList*)this)->PushList::myMap.std::map<:_Key, _Tp, _Compare,    _Alloc>::find 
>
>   [with _Key = int, _Tp = std::map<:std::basic_string<:char, std::char_traits<:char>,    
>   std::allocator<:char> >, double, std::less<:std::basic_string<:char,   
>   std::char_traits<:char>,  
>   std::allocator<:char> > >, std::allocator<:std::pair<:const std::basic_string<:char, 
>   std::char_traits<:char>, std::allocator<:char> >, double> > >, _Compare =  
>   std::less<:int>, _Alloc = 
>   std::allocator<:std::pair<:const int, std::map<:std::basic_string<:char, 
>   std::char_traits<:char>, 
>   std::allocator<:char> >, double, std::less<:std::basic_string<:char, 
>   std::char_traits<:char>, 
>   std::allocator<:char> > >, std::allocator<:std::pair<:const std::basic_string<:char, 
>   std::char_traits<:char>, std::allocator<:char> >, double> > > > >](((const 
>    int&)((const int*)((int*)nodeI))))â
> ```

How can I iterate the map of map?

Comment: Where are the a-circumflex ('â') characters coming from? Are they in the original error message, or are they due to character translation issues?

Comment: The sample code (when minimal code is added so it compiles) doesn't produce the error. Please update your question with a [minimal test caste](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Do you do anything with the iterator other than check it against end()? You could use the count() method:  
    `if (myMap.count(nodeI) == 0) {  
        exit(1);  
    }`

Answer (score 4):

From the error you posted it can be seen that you are doing this from within a class member `const` function. Is there any chance that `myMap` happens to be a member of that class? If so, what you want is to use `const_iterator` instead. You should do it anyways, since you are not expecting to modify the contents of the iterated elements.